# How to explicitly define what signature does anonymous method conform to?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, anonymous-methods

I have two methods declared

```
public void MethodA(object o, Action<string> action) { }
public void MethodA(object o, Action<CustomType> action) { }
```

How can I call these functions using anonymous method? I know I can pass a pointer to a method, but I am interested in doing this using anonymous method? Currently I am getting error "Ambitious call between....."

```
MethodA(this, c => { }); // how to explicitly say that C is of type CustomType?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MethodA(this, (CustomType c) => { });
```

or if you want to explicitly state the delegate type as `Action<CustomType>`:

```
MethodA(this, (Action<CustomType>)(c => { }));
```